# [web]How to get the value of a table cell on a row when clicking a button of that row?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

in my website i want to get the value  of a cell of column 3 on each row.So that i can pass that value to database to do something.
Iam using this code:

```
var p = {
    onload: function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById("table").rows;
        for (var i = 0, ceiling = rows.length; i < ceiling; i++) {

            rows[i].onclick = function() {
                var ad_id = this.cells[5].innerHTML;
                alert(ad_id);
                $(":button").click(function() {
                    alert(ad_id);
                    if ($(this).attr("value") == "pause") {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "header.php",
                            data: {
                                'status': '0',
                                'ad_id': ad_id
                            },
                            success: function(data, success) {
                                $("#status").html(data);
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).attr("value", "play");
                        $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-play'></i> play");
                    } else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "header.php",
                            data: {
                                'status': '1',
                                'ad_id': ad_id
                            },
                            success: function(data, success) {
                                $("#status").html(data);
                                alert(data);

                            }
                        });
                        $(this).attr("value", "pause");
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

but the problem is when i click the pause button Its acting weird.Any other ways to do this.

Comment: what i want to do is when i click the button,i want to get the value of a cell that is in the same row as the button.

Comment: Explain "weird" mate..!!

Comment: Yes.I think its because of the two click functions,on first click it works properly but on next click it do twice the function done on first click and it goes at that rate.did u get wht I mean?if u didn't get I can give u the code of my site

Comment: so the second time the function is called,the value of `ad_id` is undefined..??

Comment: No not undefined.its working properly.on first click the button pause pauses the ad and change the button to play but on next click on play button,the buttons text first changes to pause then changes to play then changes to pause again and this goes on on the next clicks

Comment: Can anyone please check it by creating a table with Id=table

Comment: this is the header.php:if(isset($_POST['status']) && isset($_POST['ad_id'])){
 if( $_POST['status'] == '0'){
  echo "paused";
 }else if($_POST['status'] == '1'){
  echo "played";
 }
 
}